# Minimum distance between two boats travelling in different velocities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question:** Boat $A$ was $100$ km south of boat $B$ at $9:00$ AM. If boat $A$ travels towards the north with the speed of $20$ km/h, and boat $B$ travels towards the east with the speed of $15$ km/h, when were they nearest to each other?

**PS:** I don't need the answer to the problem, I just need someone to guide me on how to answer this. Any leads appreciated!

Comment: Hint: in both answers so far, they tell you to use calculus to minimise the distance. But you will find that it is much easier to minimise the _square_ of the distance, and then take its square root. A handy trick to remember!

Answer (score 0):

If $f(t)$ is the distance between the two boats at time $t$, then you want to find the minimizer of $f$. So your task is to a) write down what $f(t)$ is using the information given in the problem, and b) find which $t$ minimizes $f$ using standard calculus techniques.

Answer (score 0):

When doing optimization problems, first identify the quantity that is to be optimized.  Usually you can find it by looking for a superlative like “most” or “best” or some other “-est”.  In this case, the superlative is *nearest*.  *Nearest* means minimum *distance*.  So distance between the boats is our dependent variable.

To find the independent variable, look again at the question: “*when* were the boats nearest to each other?  That describes a moment of *time*.

Therefore, express the distance between the boats as a function of time.  Use calculus to minimize that function.